# Firing a handler once for each actual change in an HTML input element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I want to trigger an event handler *once* per each *actual change* in an input field.  For example, to validate (per keypress) entry of a credit card number (the change must be on *each* change so debouncing/throttling is not the answer).

I cannot use [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference/input) alone as IE9 will not trigger this event from backspaces or cut/delete.

I cannot use `keyup` alone as this does not handle changes from a mouse (eg. pasting).

I cannot use `change` because this only fires on `blur`.

I can do `$('input').bind('input keyup', handler)` but this will fire two separate events most of the time.  Assume that the handler is expensive and running it twice is unacceptable.

I can wrap the handler so that it only runs if the current value is different to the last checked but is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are doing with checking the last input is what you need to do.

This is one way you can do it to store the last value.

```
function handler(){ 
    var tb = jQuery(this);
    var currentValue = tb.val();
    if (tb.data("lastInput") !== currentValue) {
        tb.data("lastInput", currentValue);
        console.log("The current value is " + currentValue);
    } 
}
$('input').bind('input keyup', handler);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfQWr/)

You could always extend jQuery if you really do not want that logic in your function. It is a bunch more code, but one method.

```
(function(){
    $.fn.oneinput = function(callback) {        
        function testInput(){ 
            var tb = jQuery(this);
            var currentValue = tb.val();
            if (tb.data("lastInput") !== currentValue ) {
                tb.data("lastInput",currentValue );
                if(callback) { 
                    callback.call(this) 
                };
            }
            return this;
        }    
        jQuery(this).bind("keyup input", testInput);
    };
}(jQuery));

$('input').oneinput( function(){ console.log(this.value); });
​
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZfQWr/1/)

Comment: @Dr.Molle So add paste to the event list

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the handler to return a value, you can make it `return false` so that it doesn't fire up a second time.

Comment: No, as these are separate events `return false`, `event.stopPropagation()` etc will not work

Answer (score 0):

I think the you have to use `setInterval` to moniter the change in the text box

try this [demo](http://jsbin.com/agusiq/9/edit)

```
objTextBox = document.getElementById("trackChange");
oldValue = objTextBox.value;

console.log(oldValue);

function track_change()
   {
     if(objTextBox.value != oldValue)
     {
       oldValue = objTextBox.value;
       console.log("changed")
     }

   }

setInterval(function() { track_change()}, 100);
```

**Note:** I don't personally think that this is the best solution.But I cant find a better and at leat it will work for sure in every case keyboard or mouse change ;)

Comment: This solution is similar to my current solution of wrapping the handler in a check for a changed value, but this has a much higher overhead

Comment: And if you need to monitor 100 checkboxes, you need 100 timers?

Comment: no you can just create a array of 100 checkbox and check them in the loop for the single function

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    $('input').bind('keyup cut paste', function (event) {
         console.log('value changed');
    });
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sXvK2/1/

Comment: Doesn't handle backspaces in IE9 or deleting via the mouse

Comment: updated the answer to handle cut by mouse. backspace works for me in IE9

Comment: Sorry, this would handle backspaces.  However, loosing the input handler seems risky as it fails on edge cases like deleting via mouse and input/editing via dragging

Answer (score -3):

What about

```
$el.bind('input', handler);
$el.bind('keyup', handler);
...
```

Comment: fire two separate events most times

Comment: This is no different to my example of `$('input').bind('input keyup', handler)`